# How to get the params value of plugin in the component area in joomla2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have tried to get the `plugin params` in the `component area`, but i didn't get the result.

Is there anyway to get the values.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

May this will help you- [Read more](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/joomla-dev-cms/B0poaDA9Jj4)

`JPluginHelper::getPlugin($type, $plugin)`  //It will return the plugin

**For Example-**

```
$plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('authentication', 'ldap');
//$params = new JParameter($plugin->params);//backward compatibility
$params = new JRegistry($plugin->params);//Joomla 1.6 Onward
echo $params->get('param_name','default_value');
```

`$params` will function like normal `JParameter` object and enable you to get values.

Note: Use [JRegistry](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.Registry.Registry.html) Instead of JParameter

Comment: Use JRegistry instead of JParameter since Joomla 3

Answer (score 13):

`JParameter` was deprecated in Joomla v1.6.x,Joomla v2.5.x & Joomla v3.0.x.. [reference](https://twitter.com/hans2103/status/256367013000273920)

If you want to decode the params value,use `JRegistry` instead of `JParameter`

**Example**

```
$plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('system', 'sslredirect');
$params = new JRegistry($plugin->params);
echo $params->get('param_name','default_value');
```

*Deprecation message in `parameter.php`*

```
// Deprecation warning.
JLog::add('JParameter::__construct is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of a Joomla code in PHP that let's you access plugin parameters anywhere inside Joomla

```
// Get plugin 'my_plugin' of plugin type 'my_plugin_type'
$plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('my_plugin_type', 'my_plugin');


// Check if plugin is enabled
if ($plugin)
{
    // Get plugin params
    $pluginParams = new JRegistry($plugin->params);

    $param1 = $pluginParams->get('param1');
    $param2 = $pluginParams->get('param2');
    $param3 = $pluginParams->get('param3');
}
```